# Can I import HTML5 project into Unity?

Tags: android, html, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality

I am new to augmented reality. Can I import HTML5 project into Unity as layer in augmented reality project for android using vuforia?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you can not import HTML5 into Unity but now with Unity3D 5 you can export your game or Scene to HTML5.